# How to merge two dataframes with replacement/creation of rows depending on existence in first df?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, I am looking for the simplest operation to get df3.

I want to **replace** rows in `df1` with rows from `df2` if `id` match  (so `rbind.fill` is not a solution), and append rows from `df2` where `id` does not exist in `df1`but only for columns that exist in `df2`.

I guess I could use several joins and antijoins and then merge but I wonder if there already exists a function for that operation.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, c1 = 11:15, c2 = 16:20, c3 = 21:25)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 4:7, c1 = 1:4, c2 = 5:8)

df1
  id c1 c2 c3
  1 11 16 21
  2 12 17 22
  3 13 18 23
  4 14 19 24
  5 15 20 25

df2
  id c1 c2
  4  1  5
  5  2  6
  6  3  7
  7  4  8

df3
  id c1 c2 c3
  1  11 16 21
  2  12 17 22
  3  13 18 23
  4  1  5  24
  5  2  6  25
  6  3  7  NULL
  7  4  8  NULL
```

Comment: This has been asked before and the answer is a variant of rbind.list, namely the rbind.fill function in plyr.

Comment: I dont think that this function helps me since I need some replacement of values based on id.

Comment: OK. I think the answer to "is there a function that does all of that in one go" is "no". If you know how to doi it with SQL then you might look at the `sqldf` package. I'm also not sure your verbal description completely covers the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use {powerjoin}, make a full join and deal with the conflicts using `coalesce_xy` (which is really `dplyr::coalesce`) :

```
library(powerjoin)
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, c1 = 11:15, c2 = 16:20, c3 = 21:25)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 4:7, c1 = 1:4, c2 = 5:8)
safe_full_join(df1, df2, by= "id", conflict = coalesce_xy)
#   id c1 c2 c3
# 1  1 11 16 21
# 2  2 12 17 22
# 3  3 13 18 23
# 4  4 14 19 24
# 5  5 15 20 25
# 6  6  3  7 NA
# 7  7  4  8 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with :

```
special_combine <- function(df1, df2){
  df1_int <- df1[, colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2)]
  df1_ext <- df1[, c("id", colnames(df1)[!colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2)])]
  df3 <- bind_rows(df1_int, df2)
  df3 <- df3[!duplicated(df3$id, fromLast=TRUE), ] %>% 
    dplyr::left_join(df1_ext, by="id") %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(id)
  df3
}
```